# Sails js - model association save triggers beforeUpdate issue

Tags: sails.js, waterline

When I save a User after creating an association the User.beforeUpdate hook is triggered.

The problem I'm having is that the values argument contains the entire user object for some reason.

In the User.afterCreate hook I'm associating user Permissions to the user like this.

```
    Permission.getPermission(path,roleStr)
        .then((permission) => {
            User.findOne({id:user.id})
                .populate('permissions')
                .then((resUser) => {
                    resUser.permissions.add(permission.id);
                    resUser.save((err) => {
                        if(err) return deferred.reject(err);
                            return deferred.resolve();
                     });
                 })
            .catch((err) => {});
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("addPermissionToUser Failed", err);
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
```

After the .save() method is called User.beforeUpate is passed this object.

```
{ 
  email: 'superman@test.com',
  firstName: 'Super',
  lastName: 'SuperAdmin',
  password: '$2a$10$0snWTh65eU9L6gPFYbRAV.seyGSit5v1gefp4asL3MGGKWRlv8QwK',
  emailVerified: true,
  provider: 'local',
  profileCompleted: true,
  dob: null,
  verificationCode: '1486421848265-AU6A6NHQtY5AU2Bl',
  uid: 'super-man',
  createdAt: 2017-02-06T22:57:28.471Z,
  updatedAt: 2017-02-06T22:57:28.471Z,
  id: '5898ff58ffc05b1c221ac262' 
}
```

Because there is other logic in the beforeUpdate that transforms certain values if they are present getting the whole user object back is a problem.

Why is the user object being passed to beforeUpdate? Isn't it just supposed to be values that we explicitly posted to the User.update route?

Answer (score 0):

In case of `save` it gives you all the values present for that object but in case of `update`, it gives only the updated values.

You will have to modify your before update function accordingly.